# Eliminate [design], [software-design], and [architecture] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There are currently:

- 61 questions tagged [software-design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-design)
- 214 questions tagged [design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design)
- 47 questions tagged [architecture](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture)

Some questions are tagged with a combination of those tags.

I'm not sure what benefit these tags have.

The [[software-design] wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/software-design/info) mentions *design concepts*, *design considerations*, and *modeling language* as topics, but I find those to be nebulous terms.  As for the characteristics to be avoided (*rigidity*, *fragility*, and *immobility*), we would consider them routinely in every review anyway, right?

The [[design] wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/design/info) just seems to have a lot of words that don't say anything.

The [[architecture] wiki](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/architecture/info) also doesn't say much, but at least it's brief.

In the worst case, the tags' existence encourages [questions that are not strictly code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/31071/9357) and [questions that are clearly off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36967/design-advice-for-class-creation-based-on-user-selection).

Would anyone else be in favour of eliminating these tags?  Or perhaps someone could enlighten me instead.  If we don't eliminate them, then surely at least [design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) and [software-design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-design) should be synonymized?

Comment: This is also making me think of the [architecture] tag, which can also attract off-topic questions.

Comment: @Jamal Let's just discuss all three tags at once, then!

Comment: A (possible) 3-entree meal for Trogdor! :-)

Comment: I believe Design & Architecture questions belong to Programmers SE.

Answer (score 10):

I believe [architecture](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/architecture) is *especially* worthy of burnination as it's [specifically off-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> - **Higher-level architecture** and design of software systems

The wiki even supports this:

> Architecture encompasses the process, artifacts and **high-level structure** of a solution.

The tag also already has several closed questions.  Here's one that stands out to me, which also happens to be tagged with [design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design):

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/36967/design-advice-for-class-creation-based-on-user-selection

Comment: Academia.SE has an undergraduate tag though undergraduate-level questions are off-topic: it's for asking questions about teaching undergraduates. Similarly not all 'architecture' questions are off-topic here: it's questions which _only_ ask about architecture and which _don't include code for review_ that are off-topic.

Comment: @ChrisW Could you provide examples of good [tag:architecture] questions, either existing or hypothetical? (Perhaps you should respond as an answer rather than as a comment.)

Comment: @200_success Possibly a question about [an 'architectural' design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_architecture_styles_and_patterns): "Here's some code which implements Model-View-Controller: [_inserts code here_] Am I doing it right? What about [_this problematic detail_]?" Maybe the tag isn't worthwhile and there are no associated good questions. My (perhaps frivolous or nit-picky) point was only that, the fact that a word is included in the off-topic list in the FAQ doesn't always/necessarily imply that it's an unusable tag.

Comment: @ChrisW We do have a [tag:design-patterns] tag. As I see it, [tag:design-patterns] are on-topic for Code Review, but [tag:architecture] questions belong on Programmers SE.

Comment: @200_success Fair enough. Questions like [Refactoring my simple model-view-presenter architecture](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/39405/34757) could be [design-patterns] instead. It's true that many of the architecture questions are mis-tagged.

Comment: What should one infer from the fact that the [software-design] tag has "33 followers": does that mean the tag is useful to many people?

Comment: @ChrisW: Keep in mind that 200_success is also contemplating synonymization.  I'm not sure how following works in relation to that, but it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: I agree and would put forth that "architecture" in its definitive form obviates code. Architectural questions are by definition high-level, and anyone tagging a code-specific question with [architecture] is probably mistaken in their definition of the tag or on the wrong site.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that these three tag can represent off-topic questions, I'll hold off on contacting SE until any remaining off-topic questions from these tags are found and closed.

**EDIT:** Cleanup has been completed and the request has been sent to SE.  The question will receive [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) momentarily.