# Is it time for [design] to finally resign?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blacklist-request

After a consensus was reached in [this post](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/eliminate-design-software-design-and-architecture-tags), the [design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag was burninated.  Since that time, I've seen it recreated a few times by different users (those that didn't know about this tag's history).  It was removed and eventually burninated again each time, without any responses from those users.

However, users coming with off-topic design questions can still create this tag *without* seeing the feedback that's shown when trying to create a blacklisted tag.  I think that this tag should finally be blacklisted so that users can become aware that questions solely about design don't belong here.  Sure, it's not the only problematic tag we've had, but architecture and pseuodcode questions seem to come up rarely.

Be aware that this is *not* similar to the [design-patterns](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns) tag.  It is used with questions with *complete* code that follow some design pattern, which is on-topic.  On the other hand, questions with the [design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design) tag usually have incomplete code, as the focus is on the current approached design, not on the code itself.

Comment: PLEASE! DO IT! Seriously...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've blacklisted [design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design). Users who try to use the tag will get [this warning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217915/allow-adding-a-specific-message-guidance-to-blacklists):

[image: Please don't use design as a tag, it isn't useful for identifying questions. Rather, please make certain that you've included any language tags that apply, so folks following them will be likely to see your question. [More info on meta.](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/should-design-finally-be-blacklisted)]

Answer (score 6):

Yes please, blacklist [design](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design).